# Find $\lim \sup$ and $ \lim \inf$ of the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Find $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of the following sequence
>
> (i)  $\frac{n}{4}-[\frac{n}{4}]$

How to solve it. I am in trouble to solve them.

Comment: Have you tried plotting them? Might give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

consider limits of subsequences

$(u_{4n}), \; (u_{4n+1}), \;(u_{4n+2})$ and $(u_{4n+3})$.

for the middle one.
$$u_n=\frac{n}{4}-\lfloor \frac{n}{4} \rfloor$$.

$$u_{4n}=0$$
$$u_{4n+1}=n+\frac{1}{4}-\lfloor n+\frac{1}{4}\rfloor =\frac{1}{4}$$
$$u_{4n+2}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$u_{4n+3}=\frac{3}{4}$$

thus $\liminf=0$ and $\limsup=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: Please solve middle one then I will solve the other two.

Comment: @user1942348 Yes you can.